# How to convert a json to avro without a schema?

Tags: python, json, avro

The structure of my jsons will be different, so it is really hard to set a schema for every event. Is there any way programatically to infer fields from the json and define the schema? I'm using Python.

Answer (score 0):

Avro requires a schema.

If you have dynamic fields, you can use Avro `map`, but the value types need to be consistent within the map

> programatically to infer fields from the json

You can `json.loads` into a `dict`, and use `dict.keys()` to get the field names, but parsing the types of the keys would be more complicated